# How to calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{6000} - (\sin x)^{6000}}{x^2(\sin x)^{6000}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate this limit
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{6000} - (\sin x)^{6000}}{x^2(\sin x)^{6000}}$$

What's the method?

The answer is $1000$.

Comment: Did you try applying L'Hopital's rule (i.e. taking the limit of the ratio of the derivatives of the numerator and denominator)? Note: you may need to use the rule more than once if possible.

Comment: Taylor series and binomial approximations look easier.

Comment: Are you (rather sadistically) *forced* to use L'H?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ok, one way to intimidate students is to use large numbers like 6000 in questions. A simple tool to beat this strategy of examiner is to replace the big number by a generic symbol say $n$. We thus calculate the limit $$f(n) = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{n} - \sin^{n}x}{x^{2}\sin^{n}x}$$ where $n$ is a positive integer. The answer for the question is $f(6000)$.

We have
\begin{align}
f(n) &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{n} - \sin^{n}x}{x^{2}\sin^{n}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{x - \sin x}{x^{3}\cdot\dfrac{\sin x}{x}}\cdot\dfrac{{\displaystyle \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}x^{i}\sin^{n - 1 - i}x}}{\sin^{n - 1}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x - \sin x}{x^{3}}\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^{i}\notag\\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} 1\cdot \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos x}{3x^{2}}\text{ (via L'Hospital's Rule)}\notag\\
&= \frac{n}{6}\notag
\end{align}
and hence the desired answer is $f(6000) = 1000$.

Comment: I could not understand it from the step where you used the summation sign. How did you do that? Also can you please tell me to solve it using L Hopital rule.

Comment: @HarryKarwasra: The first step where I introduce the summation sign in easy. I split $x^{n} - \sin^{n}x$ using the formula $$a^{n} - b^{n} = (a - b)(a^{n - 1} + a^{n - 2}b + \cdots + ab^{n - 2} + b^{n - 1}$$ which is written compactly as $$a^{n} - b^{n} = (a - b) \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}a^{i}b^{n - 1 - i}$$ This is how numerator is handled. For denominator I write $$x^{2}\sin^{n}x = x^{3}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot \sin^{n - 1}x$$

Comment: @HarryKarwasra: Further the $\sin^{n - 1}x$ in denominator is put with the summation and then it can be taken as denominator of each term in summation and this leads to $$\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}\frac{x^{i}\sin^{n - 1 - i}x}{\sin^{n - 1}x} = \sum_{n = 0}^{n - 1}\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^{i}$$ Now each term in summation tends to limit $1$ and hence this factor I take out separately from the limit operation. This leads to $n$ (summing $1$ for $n$ times). Next factor is $(x - \sin x)/x^{3}$ and this on L'Hospital gives $(1 - \cos x)/(3x^{2})$.

Comment: @HarryKarwasra: The limit of $(1 - \cos x)/x^{2}$ is almost standard and can be obtained as $$\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^{2}}= \frac{(1 - \cos x)(1 + \cos x)}{x^{2}(1 + \cos x)} = \frac{1 - \cos^{2}x}{x^{2}(1 + \cos x)}$$ which simplifies to $$\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{1 + \cos x}$$ and it tends to $$1\cdot\frac{1}{1 + 1} = \frac{1}{2}$$ In total we get the desired limit as $$n \cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{n}{6}$$

Comment: @HarryKarwasra: When you are told to solve a limit via L'Hospital Rule, *it does not mean that you start applying L'Hospital Rule immediately on whatever expression is there*, but it means that *you first transform your expression into a form where it is possible, simple and useful to apply L'Hospital Rule and then apply it.* Applying L'Hospital blindly is so so bad an idea to evaluate limits.

Comment: Thank you. I have understood it now clearly.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 17):

You have
$$
\sin x=x-x^3/6+o(x^3)
$$
so
$$
(\sin x)^{6000}=x^{6000}-6000\frac{x^{6002}}{6}+o(x^{6002})
$$
Hence your limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1000x^{6002}+o(x^{6002})}{x^2(\sin x)^{6000}}
$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate this? I can't understand it.

Comment: @HarryKarwasra It's a standard application of Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 7):

Since $\sin(n+1)x=2\sin nx\cos x-\sin(n-1)x$, we have
$$\begin{align}\sin3x&=2\sin2x\cos x-\sin x=2(2\sin x\cos x)\cos x-\sin x\\
&=4\sin x(1-\sin^2 x)-\sin x=3\sin x-4\sin^3x\end{align}$$
Then $\sin x=\sin(3(x/3))=3\sin(x/3)-4\sin^3(x/3)$. Then
$$\begin{align}\frac{x^n-\sin^nx}{x^2\sin^nx}&=\frac{(3(x/3))^n-(3(\sin(x/3)-(4/3)\sin^3(x/3)))^n}{x^2\sin^nx}\\
&=\frac{(3(x/3))^n-3^n\sin^n(x/3)+n\cdot3^n(4/3)\sin^{n+2}(x/3)+O(\sin^{n+4}(x/3))}{x^2\sin^nx}\\
&=\frac{(3(x/3))^n-3^n\sin^n(x/3)}{x^2\sin^nx}+\frac{n\cdot3^n(4/3)\sin^{n+2}(x/3)}{x^2\sin^nx}+\frac{O(\sin^{n+4}(x/3)}{x^2\sin^nx}\\
&=\frac{(3(x/3))^n-3^n\sin^n(x/3)}{(3(x/3))^2(3^n\sin^n(x/3))+O(\sin^{n+2}(x/3)))}\\
&+\frac{n\cdot3^n(4/3)\sin^{n+2}(x/3)}{(3(x/3))^2(3^n\sin^n(x/3))+O(\sin^{n+2}(x/3)))}+\frac{O(\sin^{n+4}(x/3)}{x^2\sin^nx}\end{align}$$
So
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^n-\sin^nx}{x^2\sin^nx}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{3^n}{3^{n+2}}\frac{(x/3)^n-\sin^n(x/3)}{(x/3)^2\sin^n(x/3)}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{O(\sin^{n+2}(x/3))}{3^n\sin^n(x/3)}\right)}\\&+\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{4n\cdot3^{n-1}}{3^{n+2}}\frac{\sin^{n+2}(x/3)}{(x/3)^2\sin^n(x/3)}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{O(\sin^{n+2}(x/3))}{3^n\sin^n(x/3)}\right)}+\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{O(\sin^{n+4}(x/3)}{x^2\sin^nx}\\
&=\frac19\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^n-\sin^nx}{x^2\sin^nx}\frac1{1+0}+\frac{4n}{27}\frac1{1+0}+0=\frac98\frac{4n}{27}=\frac n6=\frac{6000}6=1000\end{align}$$
Sort of like the Taylor series approach but using trigonometric identities instead. That $O(\sin^{n+4}(x/3))$ term represents further terms of the binomial expansion which have at least the factor $\sin^{n+4}(x/3)$, so their limits when divided merely by $\sin^{n+2}(x/3)$ are all zero. We are, of course, using
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x}x=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(x/3)}{(x/3)}=1$$

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**
Divide denominator and numerator by $x^{6000}$ then use $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin(x)} x =1$

You get: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 -  (\frac {\sin x} x)^{6000}}{x^2}  $$
Now apply L'Hospital:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{- 6000 (\frac {\sin x} x)^{5999} (\frac {\sin x} x )'} {2x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{- 6000 ( (\frac {\sin x} x )'} {2x}
$$ then again L'Hospital after calculating $(\frac {\sin x} x )'$ etc.

Comment: That is not enough to handle the difference of terms in the numerator, is it?

Comment: @ClementC. No, L'Hospital must be repeatedly applied.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is pretty useless for the results *per se*, much shorter proofs have been given. Honestly, it took me some time to write it, and I could non just abandon it in the forest.

[EDIT] Its intent is to play with standard inequalities, that are useful to keep in mind, and keep them as long as possible, without using de l'Hôpital rule, which I revere for the insight. However it requires some care, and probably [should mention Johan Bernoulli in its name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#History). Keeping inequalities may provide you with convergence rate estimates.

The function (call it $f(x)$) is even. Borrowing from @Paramanand Singh notation, it can be factorized as:

$$f(x) = \frac{1 - \left(\frac{\sin x }{x}\right)^n}{x^2 \left(\frac{\sin x }{x}\right)^n}\,.$$

We use  standard inequalities close enough to $0^+$:
$$ 1-ny \le (1-y)^n \le 1-ny + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} y^2$$
for $n>0$ and 
$$ x - \frac{x^3}{6} \le \sin x \le x - \frac{x^3}{6} +  \frac{x^5}{5!} $$
hence
$$ 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} \le \frac{\sin x }{x} \le 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} +  \frac{x^4}{5!}\,.$$

From the last one, we see that $\left(\frac{\sin x }{x}\right)^n \to 1$, so we forget about it and study $g(x) = f(x)\left(\frac{\sin x }{x}\right)^n$.

By replacing above $y$ by $ \frac{x^2}{6} $ or  $ \frac{x^2}{6} - \frac{x^4}{5!}$ , we have:
$$ n x^2 \left(\frac{1}{6} - \frac{x^2}{5!}\right) - \frac{n(n+1)x^4}{2}\left(\frac{1}{6} - \frac{x^2}{5!}\right) ^2\le 1 - \left(\frac{\sin x }{x}\right)^n \le n\left(\frac{x^2}{6} \right)$$
hence
$$\frac{n}{6}+a_nx^2+b_n x^4+c_nx^6\le g(x) \le \frac{n}{6}$$
with constants $a_n,b_n,c_n $ which you can compute explicitly, especially if you want some rate of convergence, for instance I got $a_n = -\frac{n(5n+8)}{360}$. And for your question of course the limit is $1000 = 6000/6$.

Here is a visual simulation of the bounds for function $g(x)$, only for $n=4$ for numerical reasons:

[image: Numerical bounds]

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{6000} - (\sin x)^{6000}}{x^2(\sin x)^{6000}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^{6000} - 1}{x^2}$$

Lets call $u(x)=\frac{x}{\sin x}$ and apply L'Hospital twice:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^{6000} - 1}{x^2}=3000\lim_{x \to 0}\left[ u'^2+u\cdot u''(x)\right]$$

Evaluate the last limit and note that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{6000} - (\sin x)^{6000}}{x^2(\sin x)^{6000}} =\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{6000-1-1}x^r\sin^{6000-r}}{(\sin x)^{6000}}$$

Now,
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{6000-1}x^r\sin^{6000-1-r}}{(\sin x)^{6000}}=\sum_{r=0}^{6000-1}\left(\dfrac x{\sin x}\right)^r$$

For the rest, see http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/solve-lim-x-gt-0-x-sin-x-x-3-211979

Comment: There's something wrong: you should have $x^3$ in the denominator of the first limit, because $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^2}=0$.

Comment: @egreg, Yes, what's wrong with this as the other limit is finite

Comment: You have an off by one exponent in the sines under the summation: it should be $(\sin x)^{6000-1-r}$. Since the limit is $1000$, there *must* be an error! See Paramanand Singh's answer, where the computation is carried out correctly.

Comment: @egreg, Hey, that's a rectified & generalized copy of my answer:)

Comment: Downvote removed

Answer (score 0):

A lovely cheat that complex analysis offers:

Recall that the Laurent expansion of $\csc(z)$ is $\frac{1}{z}(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+o(z^4))$.

Apply this mindlessly to the question to obtain

$\frac{z^{5998}}{(\sin(x))^{6000}}-\frac{1}{z^2}=\frac{z^{5998}}{z^{6000}}(1+\frac{6000}{6}z^{2}+o(z^4))-\frac{1}{z^2}$ and the answer pops right out.

Comment: The expansion $\csc x=\frac1x\left(1+\frac16x^2+O(x^4)\right)$ (but with $O(x^4)$, not $o(x^4)$...) does not require complex analysis, only to know the standard expansions $\sin x=x-\frac16x^3+O(x^5)$ and $\frac1{1-x}=1+x+O(x^2)$.

Comment: Yes, but those who have seen Laurent series in action are more sensitive to them.