# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\tan x)^{2008}-(\arctan x)^{2008}}{x^{2009}}$ without using Taylor series.

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\tan x)^{2008}-(\arctan x)^{2008}}{x^{2009}}$$ without using Taylor series.

I have a solution using  $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-\arctan x}{x^2}=0$, but I would really like to see a different idea.

Comment: $0{{}}$ surely?

Comment: Yes, isn't it right?

Comment: Why do you want a different idea when the adapted tool is the Taylor expansion ?

Comment: I know the straightforward solution is the one with Taylor series, but I'm just curious to see a beautiful idea.

Comment: It's an odd function....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Not useful unless we can prove it is bounded.

Comment: I personally prefer the solution which you have indicated in your answer. Any other solution would probably use more sophisticated tools compared to your answer which uses algebra of limits.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can define

$$f(x) = \left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\right)^{2008}\qquad g(x) = \left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\right)^{2008}$$

then use
$$\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x} \longrightarrow f^\prime(0) - g^\prime(0)$$

**Remark**

The following useful inequalities hold

$$|\tan(x) -x| = \int_0^{|x|}\tan^2(t)dt\le \tan^2(x)\int_0^{|x|}dt\le |x| \tan^2(x) \quad \text{for }|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

and
$$|\arctan(x) - x| = \int_0^{|x|}\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}dt\le
\int_0^{|x|}t^2dt\le \frac{|x|^3}{3}\quad\text{for } x\in{\mathbb R}$$
They imply that $\frac{\tan(x)}{x} - 1 = o(x)$ and $\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}-1 = o(x)$, hence $f^\prime(0)$ and $g^\prime(0)$ exist and are $0$.

Comment: Ingenious! =D Have (+1) and then some.

Comment: You also need to require $f(0)=g(0)=1$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt This was implicit. I only need to know the derivatives of $\tan$ and $\arctan$.

Comment: +1   for this artistic  proof....it looks like a Cezanne's masterpiece

Comment: @Isham I'd dream to be a Cezanne of mathematics, but things aren't that easy. Notice that $f^\prime(0)$ and $g^\prime(0)$ are zero without calculation because $f$ and $g$ are even functions.

Comment: When can we say that if $f$ is an even function, then $f'(0)=0$? Because for $f(x)=|x|$, this is not true.

Comment: @Shroud You are right. One needs to know that $f^\prime(0)$ exists! There are a few ways to prove it here.

Comment: I think evaluating those derivatives of $f, g$ is not so straightforward.

Comment: Thus for example evaluation of $f'(0)$ is based on derivative of $x^{2008}$ as well as the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\tan x - x} {x^{2}}=0$ which brings us back to the solution indicated by OP in his post.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Meh, I think the OP does not mind the use of $\lim\frac{\tan x-x}{x^2}$ or similar. The only real restriction I see is Taylor expansion

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : I have shown in my answer that the limit in question crucially depends on limit of $(\tan x - x) /x^{2}$ and this limit itself can be shown to be $0$ without the use of Taylor.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh see my edits above.

Comment: That's a little more complicated than using the inequalities $\sin x <x<\tan x$ but correct.

Comment: You can't be no Cezanne if your username is gribouillis

Answer (score 7):

The solution you have indicated is the one which is the simplest. But you are perhaps under the impression that it uses Taylor series. This is not the case.

---

Note that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x - x} {x^{2}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x - x\cos x} {x^{2}\cos x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x - x\cos x} {x^{2}}$$ and then you can split the limit as $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x - x} {x^{2}}+\lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot\frac{1-\cos x} {x^{2}}$$ The second limit is clearly $0\cdot (1/2)=0$ and the the first one is also $0$ via Squeeze Theorem. To apply Squeeze Theorem let's consider the case when $x\to 0^{+}$. Then we have $\sin x <x<\tan x$ which is equivalent to $$\cos x <\frac{\sin x} {x} <1$$ or $$x\cdot\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}}<\frac{\sin x-x} {x^{2}}<0$$ and applying Squeeze gives us the desired result. The case $x\to 0^{-}$ is handled by putting $x=-t$.

Thus we have established that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x - x} {x^{2}}=0\tag{1}$$ and multiplying this limit with $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^{2}}{\tan^{2}x}=1$ we get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-x} {\tan^{2}x}=0$$ Putting $x=\arctan t$ and replacing $t$ by $x$ we get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\arctan x} {x^{2}}=0\tag{2}$$ Adding limit equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x - \arctan x} {x^{2}}=0\tag{3}$$ The limit in question has got [huge exponents as an intimidation tool which we can beat by replacing it with a generic symbol $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1786395/72031).

We can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L &=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan^{n}x-\arctan^{n}x}{x^{n+1}}\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x - \arctan x} {x^{2}}\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{\tan x} {x}\right)^{n-1-i}\left(\frac{\arctan x} {x} \right)^{i} \notag\\
&=0\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1\cdot 1=0\notag
\end{align}

---

If the exponent in denominator is $n+2$ then the problem necessitates the use of tools like L'Hospital's Rule and Taylor series to get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x - \arctan x} {x^{3}}=\frac{2}{3}$$ and as explained above $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan^{n}x-\arctan^{n}x}{x^{n+2}}=\frac{2n}{3}$$

Answer (score -2):

without Taylor series,
you can use 
$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...+b^{n-1})$ identity.
$$\quad{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\tan x)^{2008}-(\arctan x)^{2008}}{x^{2009}}=\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\tan x-\arctan x)(\tan^{2007} x+\tan^{2006}x\arctan x+...+\arctan^{2007}x)}{x^{2009}}=\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{((\tan x-\arctan x))(\tan^{2007} x+\tan^{2006}x\arctan x+...+\arctan^{2007}x)}{x^{2009}}=\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\tan x-\arctan x)(\tan^{2007} x+\tan^{2006}x\arctan x+...+\arctan^{2007}x)}{x^{2009}}=\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\tan x-\arctan x)(x^{2007} +x^{2006} x^1+...+x^{2007})}{x^{2009}}=\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\tan x-\arctan x)2008(x^{2007} )}{x^{2009}}=\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\tan x-\arctan x)2008(1 )}{x^2}=\\
\underbrace{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\tan x-\arctan x)2008(1 )}{x^2}=\\}_{\large \text{With respect to "I have a solution using "}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-\arctan x}{x^2}=0} }\\$$

Comment: You seem to have misread important restraints of the problem at hand.

Comment: How does $\frac{2x^3}{3}$ pop out ?

Comment: @MariosGretsas :Oh sorry , i'll correct it

Comment: I mean in the third line

Comment: @MariosGretsas :Agin I used Taylor , but now I don't use it .

Comment: "Agin I used Taylor , but now I don't use it ." could you try again? Are you saying you don't understand what you did?

Comment: I don't mean any offense, your last comment was just very unclear.

Comment: The part where you replace all those powers of $\tan x, \arctan x$ by $x^{2007}$ is simply wrong. - 1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That's not really a problem though, as
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan^j(x)\arctan^{n-j}(x)}{x^n} = \underbrace{\left(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan(x)}{x}\right)^j}_{=\,1}\cdot\underbrace{\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\right)^{n-j}}_{=\,1} = 1$$

Comment: @adfriedman: that does not mean you can replace $\tan^{n} x$ with $x^{n} $. The equation which you have written is the key but it should be used in the way I have done it in my answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh this wasn't my answer, and what was written by Khosrotash isn't entirely justified, I was just addressing the fact that that step can easily be fixed by equality I gave.

Comment: @adfriedman: yes I know that. I expect the problem to be fixed with a minor update. But until the update is done it is mathematically wrong. Such steps do not always lead to a correct answer.