# Why my method of solving this question is incorrect ? Evaluate: $\lim_{x→0} \frac{x^{6000} - (\sin x)^{6000}}{x^2(\sin x)^{6000}}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

so for solving this question I did the following steps can anyone tell me why my method is wrong.
please explain in detail I want to clarify my concept of limits

Question
\begin{aligned}
&\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{x^{6000}-(\sin x)^{6000}}{x^{2}(\sin x)^{6000}}\\
\end{aligned}

My solution
\begin{aligned}
&\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left[\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^{6000} \frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right]\\
\end{aligned}
As we know that
\begin{aligned}
&\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^{6000}=1
\end{aligned}
So
\begin{aligned}
&\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\
\end{aligned}

**so according to me, the answer should be "$0$"**

**but the answer is  $1000$**

please explain with a full explanation and it would be better if you give some examples too.

Comment: As for where the argument went wrong: Theorems about "the limit of a product is the product of the limits" require that limits of the individual factors exist. But $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ doesn't exist (i.e., is not a real number).

Comment: you may not understand the language but can you tell me why the method shown in this video is correct https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer/find-the-value-of-limx-rarr-0x6000-sinx6000-100x2sinx6000-9651045

Comment: See related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1786112/72031

Comment: Just like you don't have $\sqrt{a+b} =\sqrt {a} +\sqrt {b} $ in algebra there are rules for calculus. In general don't assume more than what the standard limit theorems mention.

Comment: so is the solution shown in video correct

Comment: I can understand the language of the video and advise you stay away from it. Open up your textbook try to learn limit laws and ask questions on limit laws until and unless your understanding of those laws is complete.

Comment: The video simply fails to explain why we can replace some expression in denominator with its limit and not do the same in numerator. The thing has nothing to do with $0/0$ or numerator and denominator. Rather it is related to a deep understanding of limit laws. Please go through my linked answer (see next comment) and ask me if something is not clear.

Comment: You can't replace a part of an expression with its limit. That's invalid and not permitted by any law of limits. For more details see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031

Comment: it's just because of the people in this community of math stack exchange that many students like me have to struggle on the web to find answers to their concept there is no problem in the question but god know people have downvoted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue comes in where you break up the limit.

Here's the underlying logic of your proof written out more fully:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^{6000} \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^{6000} \frac{1}{x^2} - \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^{6000} \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^2} - \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}$$

$$= (1)\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^2} - \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2} = 0.$$

Breaking up the limits this way is only valid if all of the limits are finite, which is not true for $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}.$

Comment: in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU8NjilJ86E&t=648s&ab_channel=GoatMath at 10:36 nothing like this is mentioned that splitting needs the limits to be finite     , so is the video wrong

Comment: The video is just fine, they mention the rules don't always work. This is one of the conditions where the rules don't work, and they show this with the $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 - x$ example.

Comment: ok so should i say according to your answer ,splitting of limit is only possible if both the functions are finite and not indeterminate form

Comment: I believe this is the case, yes. By the way, this is why in the Doubtnut video he is able to take the $\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{6000}$ out from the denominator in the video: he is breaking the limit over multiplication, which is valid there because if we assume the original limit has a finite value, then both of the limits which he splits into are finite so use of the rule is justified.

Comment: are you talking about "youtube" video or "doubtnut" one

Comment: The doubtnut one, the one going over his solution to this question

Comment: Okay,thanks Sir

Comment: Of course, have a good one

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\cdot g(x)=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$ will only work if both the limits are finite in the right hand side

For finite integer $n>0, a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots +ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})\implies$ $$\dfrac{x^n-\sin^nx}{x^2\sin^nx}=\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\cdot\dfrac x{\sin x}\left(\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\dfrac x{\sin x}\right)^{n-r}\right)$$

Now use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)  and $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem in your solution is that you have to apply limit to each and every function involved in the expression simultaneously.

But what you did, If I repeat but with the slight variation, you will realize
that, no what you are doing is a very big mistake.

first plugin $x=0$ in the numerator's $x^{6000}$ it vanishes and you left with $\frac{sinx^{6000}}{x^2.sinx^{6000}}$

Now you left with $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}$ which is not defined.

so coming back to your way if you plugin $x=0$ to the second step you will get $(\frac{1}{0^2}-\frac{1}{0^2})$ which is not equal to zero.

there is one more example I have to explain to you and that is

calculate $lim_{x \to\infty}
\frac{2}{\pi}$$(n+1)$.$\arccos\frac{1}{n}$)- $n$

one of the wrong solution similar to which you did,

plug in  $x=\infty$ in $cos$ term keeping all other terms safe as it is and you will get $\frac{\pi}{2}$ canceling $\frac{2}{\pi}$ and the remaining thing is $(n+1)-(n)$ = $1$ which is the wrong answer so never plug in in some part leaving others intact, limits should be applied simultaneously. Well, I leave it as an exercise for you to find the correct answer with the correct method.

I hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: check this solution, in this solution also the limits are not applied simultaneously https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer/find-the-value-of-limx-rarr-0x6000-sinx6000-100x2sinx6000-9651045

Comment: It is not really necessary to apply limit to each part simultaneously. You can replace a part by its limit if the part is a term of a factor in the overall expression. Also if the part is a factor you should ensure that its limit is non-zero.

Comment: sorry, I can't see this video, because this is not a reliable site. In this, you can easily find such videos which can completely tremble your concepts. sometimes you can get an answer by the wrong method, it is totally based on your luck. But if things are in the product and by putting the value there is not any effect in indeterminacy you can answer (always I hope this for you). I think it would be better if you ask your maths teacher or some good books. you can also see Ciapan's answer it is simple and easy to understand. once again sorry if my words are harsh. thanks

Comment: @ParamanandSingh if the limit by substituting before we get non zero then it is correct then why in the example I have given got a wrong answer.

Comment: and this is not the only there are a lot.

Comment: @satyanshuu: $\arccos(1/n)$ is not a factor of the overall expression. You should check the detailed answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031

Comment: Your profile states that you are a senior to me and much more knowledgeable than me, but these are the things that my teacher had taught and what I have read in books.

Comment: But if it is the matter of some competitive exams then it works well as a shortcut but fundamentally it is wrong.

Comment: what you have discussed in your detailed answer; I have written above I suppose - ( But if things are in the product and by putting the value there is not any effect in indeterminacy you can answer (always I hope this for you))

Answer (score 0):

ERROR:

Transforming
$$\left(\frac x{\sin x}\right)^{6000} \frac 1{x^2}$$
with
$$\lim _{x \to 0}\left(\frac x{\sin x}\right)^{6000}=1$$
into
$$\frac 1{x^2}$$
to conclude
$$\lim _{x \to 0}\left[\left(\frac x{\sin x}\right)^{6000} \frac 1{x^2}-\frac 1{x^2}\right] \color{red}= \lim _{x \to 0}\left(\frac 1{x^2}-\frac 1{x^2}\right) = \lim 0 = 0$$

makes more or less the same sense as
transforming
$$\frac xx$$
with
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x = 0$$
into
$$\frac 0x$$
to conclude
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac xx \color{red}= \lim \frac 0x = \lim 0 = 0$$